# When documenting a Java program, what is the convention for documenting classes?

Tags: java, class, documentation, convention

I know that for methods, a explanation is provided and the @param, @return, and @throw. But for classes, are there any particular things that need to be included besides the explanation of the class?

Comment: Whose convention are you trying to follow?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the class level, the documentation should explain:

1. Why/when would I want to use this class?
2. How do I use this class (examples)
3. How does this class play with other classes?
4. What is unexpected/special about this class? (thread safety, global variables, ...)

All in all, the class documentation should give a broader view, showing how the class fits into the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The tendency is to not include these comments or keep them very brief and let naming conventions drive our understanding of what the class should do.  For example, a plain-old Java object (POJO) named "Address" might need very little in the way of documentation, other than what makes it truly unique.  Take a look through recent Java projects on GitHub and you'll see this to be the case.  Annotations and package names also help describe the class inherently.

If you focus more on naming, you shouldn't need to document much - other than what makes the class unique or limitations it may have.